# Platformer collision detection problem - player snapping onto sides

Tags: 2d, javascript, html-canvas, platformer

I am having problems with collision detection. I am trying to make a simple platformer but when the player is falling or moving too fast it sometimes detects the wrong collision side. I am getting the side of the collision by checking the distance between the player and the sides of a block that are exposed to the player. I also tried detecting collision one axis at a time but this glitch still occurs.

[image]

```
blockCollision: function(block) {
        if(this.x + this.width > block.x && this.x < block.x + block.width && this.y + this.height > block.y && this.y < block.y + block.height) {
            let distanceLeft = Math.abs(this.x + this.width - block.x)
            let distanceRight = Math.abs(this.x - (block.x + block.width))
            let distanceTop = Math.abs(this.y + this.height - block.y)
            let distanceBottom = Math.abs(this.y - (block.y + block.height))

            if(distanceLeft < distanceTop && distanceLeft < distanceBottom && !block.collisionSides.includes('L')){
                this.velX = 0
                this.x = block.x - this.width
            }
            if(distanceRight < distanceTop && distanceRight < distanceBottom && !block.collisionSides.includes('R')){
                this.velX = 0
                this.x = block.x + block.width
            }
            if(distanceTop < distanceLeft && distanceTop < distanceRight && !block.collisionSides.includes('T')){
                this.jumping = false
                this.velY = 0
                this.y = block.y - this.height 
            }
            if(distanceBottom < distanceLeft && distanceBottom < distanceRight && !block.collisionSides.includes('B')){
                this.velY = 0
                this.y = block.y + block.height
            }

            if(distanceLeft == distanceTop && !block.collisionSides.includes('LT')){
                this.x = block.x - this.width
                this.y = block.y - this.height
            }
            if(distanceLeft == distanceBottom && !block.collisionSides.includes('LB')){
                this.x = block.x - this.width 
                this.y = block.y + block.height
            }
            if(distanceRight == distanceTop && !block.collisionSides.includes('RT')){
                this.x = block.x + block.width
                this.y = block.y - this.height
            }
            if(distanceRight == distanceBottom && !block.collisionSides.includes('RB')){
                this.x = block.x + block.width 
                this.y = block.y + block.height
            }
        }
    }
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wojak2121/rwxn9mq2/8/)

Comment: It looks like you're facing [the same issue as this recent question, about distinguishing side-on versus top-down collisions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/177276/39518). Do any of the answers there help you?

Comment: I think it works now. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Want me to close this question as a duplicate, if the answers at the link above solved it? Or, if you found a new solution, please feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: You can close the question as a duplicate.